# NRF52XX antenna input switching

Tags: bluetooth

I want to do some expermenting with BT positioning in the NRF device. Will a QORVO QPC7512 50 Ohm switch work with two antennas feeding an nRF52811? Last time I checked Nordic no have reference design for low end product.

Comment: You'd better ask this at Nordic DevZone. PS: Even if QPC7512's max frequency is 3.3GHz, it's specialized for cable TV and satellite TV signals. So it may not provide the desired performance with BT 5.x. If you are interested, there are N/C 50 Ohm antenna connectors *(e.g. Murata's SWF series and Hirose's MS-156C series)*. But you should remove and insert the antenna every time, and you may not be able to use them with PCB antennas.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for a reference design source?